# Can localhost be both client and server for development?

Tags: c#, tcp, console

Referring to [a question I asked on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/395746/cannot-open-port-in-windows-7), which is recommended to be ask on SO.

I am developing a console application that sends packet to a remote server on a specific TCP Port (55000). I only have one computer to develop and test on. Is it still possible to debug my program; i.e. when I F5 debug, I send a test packet (from localhost) to localhost which is listening.

Also, I need to open up a port for development. I follow the [this instruction](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/open-a-port-in-windows-7s-firewall/) to open a port (55000) in Window 7.

But when I netstat, the port 55000 is not even listed (i.e. the Local Address of 0.0.0.0:55000 is not there...). I also tried restarting the computer, but persist the problem.

Comment: It is more likely to be listed under 127.0.0.1:55000. Since that's the loop back ip adress on your system.

Comment: It's not listed either. Actually nothing is listed with 127.0.0.1 in TCP listing...what is happening?

Comment: Can you maybe show us some of the code you are using to listen to the port?

Comment: Please, check your two web link. They are invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course you can. Just run the server to listen on port 55000, and then connect to localhost on port 55000.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 different sites in the IIS with different ports or you can take advanatege of 'hosts' file to assign some naming for those 2 sites

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Although keep in mind that TCP ports for request and response must be different. So, if you bind your server to some port (say 2000), then your client must send requests from different port (80 usually).

Comment: The client port should be selected automatically by the operating system.

Comment: And normally it would not be one of the lower numbers, normally it is selected from a range of higher port numbers - ones that do not block one of the assigned port numbers such as the one for HTTP...