# Does localhost refer to the client or the server?

Tags: php, dart, client-server, localhost

I have a Dart application, which communicates to the server with POST-requests. At the moment, the server is on my local machine where I also test the application in the browser, so obviously, I have to send the POST-Req to localhost. But when the server is on one computer and the client anywhere else, it seems not to work with localhost even though both the webapp and the server are hosted on the same machine.

For example, I have to replace `localhost:8080/web/info.php` with `192.168.0.6/web/info.php`if the client machine is my phone that is in the same Wlan as the server. So does that mean that a request to `localhost`from dart code refers to the client machine? I assume so but want to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localhost is just an easy way of identifying the current computer.  It does not work when trying to access another server unless you view it from the server itself.  If you want to access it from another server, you should either refer to your server by IP, or by a domain name.

Comment: in short my assumption is correct that localhost refers to the machine on which the client views the web-app? Not having to do with my use case right now but for future reference: Would that mean you could technically create a webapp that interacts with a server on the client machine?

Comment: Yup.  You can create a web app that does interact as long as you avoid referencing localhost.  If you use the IP of the server you should have no problem.  Or you can even create your own DNS alias in the HOSTS file of your client machine, though that is less recommendable since you'd have to do it to each client.

Comment: thank you but I think you misunderstood my second question. I meant if the following scenario would be possible: I have two servers, each on its own machine and one webapp, that would depending on which computer it is viewn interact with either server.

Comment: If you mean to create a server/web app that is run on the client machine which then communicates with your server, that is definitely possible.  Less useful I suppose than just running the web app from the same server, but everything has an application. And if you have two servers then you also can do the same.  That would be Server-Server communication and is common in most APIs to handle authentication.

Comment: okey, seems like I cannot formulate that clear enough. I will simply try that out anytime when I have nothing to do. Thank you for your answer to my 'real' question though :)

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, but basically you can make software communicate from any computer to any computer as long as you have yourself a network.

Answer (score 0):

According to [James McLaughlin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9516590/5595995), the localhost (http://127.0.0.1) could be server and client.

Other explanation for using the localhost for the client and server testing is at [the localhost question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516566/can-localhost-be-both-client-and-server-for-development).